# How can I select the entire range in a Monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using the following code to replace the text in my editor. (See [`executeEdits`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#interfaces/editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor.html#executeEdits).)

```js
const text = "My new text"
const range = {
  startLineNumber: 1,
  startColumn: 1,
  endLineNumber: 999999,
  endColumn: 999999
}
editor.executeEdits("", [{ range, text, forceMoveMarkers: true }])
```

Notice the `999999`s. This works, but I wonder if there's a better way to declare a range that represents "the whole editor"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see things around this

```
const range = editor.getModel().getFullModelRange(); // magic
editor.executeEdits("", [{ range, text, forceMoveMarkers: true }]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, how did you find this? I'm finding it hard to find the functions / methods I need for Monaco Editor. Any tips on this front?

Comment: i searched how to do a select all and someone suggested this

Comment: Also studying the type definitions might reveal some hidden gems.